# Converting Java calculation to plsql

Tags: calculation

Below codes are written in the Java.

```
Round(Max(value1+value2, Value3 * Value4 / 7 + Value5))
```

But needs to do the calculation part from the 11g
database itself for the columns while running the loop data will fetch all columns values from the same table.

Thanks in advance.

Trying to do the same calculation part in Oracle 11g.

Comment: Please provide what you have in Oracle.....

Comment: And, please, be clear about what what you are trying to do (see, for my attempt to help you: https://dbfiddle.uk/q6VjyM1C )  (or, when you really insist on using version 11: https://dbfiddle.uk/ybi186FX )

Comment: Previously they did this calculation in the Java end but now need to do the same one from database side. Oracle Max function will not work with two or more arguments but in Java they are doing.so just need to convert this one into Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

But you are, probably, looking for this:

```
SELECT
  value1,
  value2,
  Value3,
  Value4,
  Value5,
  -- Round(Max(value1+value2, Value3 * Value4 / 7 + Value5))
  CASE WHEN (value1+value2) > (Value3 * Value4 / 7 + Value5)
       THEN value1+value2
       ELSE Value3 * Value4 / 7 + Value5
       END as stuckoverflow
FROM test;
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/ldXzWpYX)

The `MAX()` function in Java does not exist in SQL.

You will have to use a `CASE WHEN ........ END` construction, see: https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-case/for more info.